# Power down has no response

Tags: 16.04, power-management, restart

I have been having a weird problem that, quite honestly, I don't even know how to debug.

If my laptop goes into sleep mode, when it comes back, the only way to restart or power down is by using the laptop's power button.

Pushing it does bring up the menu on screen of choices to turn off, restart, etx. But clicking them does nothing. Same from the menu, same from CLI.

Has anyone heard of something like this before? Any ideas on how to begin with this?

I have a System 76 Oryx pro. It came with 16.04, but I wiped it clean and did a reinstall from a boot disk.

Comment: What's your laptop make and model? Did you upgrade to 16.04 from previous version number ___ or was it a new install?

Comment: New install. System 76 Oryx pro